# Unstable LTE connection with SIM7600G-H 4G HAT

Tags: wireless-networking, iptables, raspberry-pi

I've used a RasperryPi 3B+ together with the SIM7600G-H 4G HAT module to build myself a home router. The HAT module is connected via mini-usb.
I managed to setup the LTE connection using qmicli with a reasonable signal:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --nas-get-signal-strength
[/dev/cdc-wdm0] Successfully got signal strength
Current:
    Network 'lte': '-74 dBm'
RSSI:
    Network 'lte': '-74 dBm'
ECIO:
    Network 'lte': '-2.5 dBm'
IO: '-106 dBm'
SINR (8): '9.0 dB'
RSRQ:
    Network 'lte': '-12 dB'
SNR:
    Network 'lte': '3.8 dB'
RSRP:
    Network 'lte': '-103 dBm'
```

I also use iptable to forward the traffic between the Ethernet port and the wwan01:

```
iptables -F
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wwan0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i wwan0 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wwan0 -j ACCEPT
```

I also have dnsmasq running on the eth0 for dns (just cache) and DHCP.
Everything seems to work fine while testing - connection is established and maintained, internet is properly shared I can run simple wgets and pings.
I do have a connection monitor script that wgets a simple page every 30sec - the connection was up for 10 days straight, without any disconnects. I can use wget to download medium files (~1G) - so far so good.

However as soon as I start really using it with a web browser(presumably large number of simultaneous connections) - the connection dies. speedtest.net for instance kills the connection reliably after about 20 seconds. Downloading single files via wget also times out after ~1.5G.

There are no errors, nothing in dmesg or syslog - simply no response. No power issues (I've a special purpose 3A adapter).

Did anyone ever came across anything similar? If not - any good way to "throttle" the routing?

Answer (score 0):

You should start by working on your mobile reception.

While your received signal strength (RSSI) is not that bad, the RSRQ (received signal received quality) and SINR (signal to noise ratio) is on the lower end, which indicates a low quality/high interference connection.

Proper positioning is important. The higher the better. Also make sure to have as much clear view as possible around the antenna. Signal reflections from buildings or other objects around the receiver can significantly reduce the signal quality.

You haven't mentioned which antenna you are using, I suspect you are using the cheap antenna which came with the HAT.
A proper antenna should make a big difference. An outdoor antenna would be ideal, if this is not possible mount the antenna around a window.

Comment: thanks for the info. I do not have any real restrictions on the on the antenna since this is for personal use. Are there any good antennas that you could recommend or technology/spec ?